# Key Error: Python Finite State Machine?

Tags: python, oop, fsm

Here is my code for a simple implementation of a Finite State Machine in Python. I have run it multiple times to no avail. When the individual state classes do inherit from the individual class, they cannot access the food and sleep variables needed to run the logic of the machine. I believe I am getting a KeyError because every time I add a new state, it resets the Current State Value to None. How might I get around this error? Is there a better/proper way to structure my classes? I am intermediate at python, however OOP concepts have been particularly challenging for me. Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
class FSM():
    def __init__(self):
        self.states = {}
        self.c_state = None

    def update(self):
        self.states[self.c_state].execute()

    def addState(self, name, handler):
        self.states[name] = handler

    def startState(self, state):
        self.c_state = state

    def changeState(self, newstate):
        print('The current state is:', self.c_state)
        self.states[self.c_state].exit()
        self.c_state = self.states[newstate]
        self.states[self.c_state].enter()

class individual():
    def __init__(self, name, food, sleep):
        self.name = name
        self.food = food
        self.sleep = sleep
        self.fsm = FSM()

class wander(individual):
    def enter(self):
        print('Entering Wander State')

    def execute(self):
        print('WANDERING')
        if self.sleep == 0:
            self.fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
        elif 25 > self.sleep > 0 and self.food > 25:
            self.fsm.changeState('WANDER')
            self.sleep -= 5
            self.food -= 5
        elif self.food < 25:
            self.fsm.changeState('EAT')

    def exit(self):
        print('Leaving Wander State')

class eat(individual):
    def enter(self):
        print('Entering Eating State')

    def execute(self):
        print('EATING')
        if self.sleep > 0 and self.food < 25:
            self.fsm.changeState('EAT')
            self.food += 5
            self.sleep -= 5
        elif self.food > 25 and self.sleep > 0:
            self.fsm.changeState('WANDER')
        elif self.sleep == 0:
            self.fsm.changeState('SLEEP')

    def exit(self):
        print('Exiting Eating State')

class sleep(individual):
    def enter(self):
        print('Entering Sleeping State')

    def execute(self):
        print('SLEEPING')
        if 50 > self.sleep > 0:
            self.fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
            self.sleep += 5
        elif self.sleep == 50 and self.food < 25:
            self.fsm.changeState('EAT')
        elif self.sleep == 50 and self.food > 25:
            self.fsm.changeState('WANDER')

    def exit(self):
        print('Exiting Sleeping State')

aaron = individual('aaron', 10, 30)
aaron.fsm.addState('WANDER', wander(aaron.name, aaron.food, aaron.sleep))
aaron.fsm.addState('EAT', eat(aaron.name, aaron.food, aaron.sleep))
aaron.fsm.addState('SLEEP', sleep(aaron.name, aaron.food, aaron.sleep))
aaron.fsm.startState('WANDER')
print(aaron.fsm.c_state)
aaron.fsm.update()

 File "C:/Users/Aaron/PycharmProjects/InDepthFSM/FSM.py", line 12, in update
    self.states[self.c_state].execute()
  File "C:/Users/Aaron/PycharmProjects/InDepthFSM/FSM.py", line 50, in execute
    self.fsm.changeState('EAT')
  File "C:/Users/Aaron/PycharmProjects/InDepthFSM/FSM.py", line 24, in changeState
    self.states[self.c_state].exit()
KeyError: None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're referring to different fsm objects when you perform your updates.

In the `execute` code snippet, when you update state, the issue is that while the `FSM` object exists for the individual object, it doesn't exist for the `eat` class, and you try to update the state of the `eat` class.

```
# Here, since self refers to the `eat` class, you are creating a new fsm object
# This means that you are in fact referring to an empty set of states.
elif self.sleep == 0:
   self.fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
```

Inheritance doesn't mean that the classes share a single `FSM` instance, so if you want to operate on the `FSM` object belonging to the individual class you need to pass the individual as an input.

That said, the `eat` piece here really shouldn't be a class, but should be a function of `individual`, rather than inheriting from it. For instance:

```
class individual(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # make object

    def eat(self):
        print('EATING')
        if self.sleep > 0 and self.food < 25:
            self.fsm.changeState('EAT')
            self.food += 5
            self.sleep -= 5
        elif self.food > 25 and self.sleep > 0:
            self.fsm.changeState('WANDER')
        elif self.sleep == 0:
            self.fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
```

in this case, `self` actually refers to the `individual` object.

I think you've got some confusions about OOP in general. Inheritance doesn't interact at all with specific object instances. Instead, it's like saying: "I need to make a new object, but let me use this old one as a template and just add to it".

What you're trying to do here is much closer to creating a singleton, which is one object that has a single state that is referred to elsewhere. Not everything is supposed to be an object. For instance, handlers are typically functions, and relying on a magic `execute` function rather than just executing a function is pretty circuitous.

Comment: Thank You so Much, My apologies for replying so late, however I have now gained a better understanding of OOP in general. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: @AaronOtillar Thank you! Happy to help. Typically when an answer helps you solve the problem on SO you accept the answer by clicking the checkmark by the question. You and I will both get rep for it.

Answer (score 0):

As Slater Tyranus mentioned, the issue is that you are making the states (`wander`, `eat` and `sleep` classes) subclasses of `individual`. This is not correct. Think of subclassing as saying something "is" something else. For example, with the class declaration `class Car(Vehicle):`, you are essentially saying that "a `Car` is a `Vehicle`", which is a true statement. However, your code implies that the `wander` state is an individual, which is not true. The other issue is that because each state is an individual, each one gets its own fsm. This is not necessary, nor should an individual have an fsm in the first place (do you have one? I don't).

I have refactored your code, and simplified the conditions in the states, correcting some other bugs in the process. Take a look and see if this works more the way that you expect:

```
class FSM(object):
    def __init__(self, individual):
        self.states = {}
        self.c_state = None
        self.individual = individual

    def update(self):
        self.states[self.c_state].execute(self)

    def addState(self, name, handler):
        self.states[name] = handler

    def startState(self, state):
        self.c_state = state

    def changeState(self, newstate):
        print('The current state is:', self.c_state)
        self.states[self.c_state].exit()
        self.c_state = newstate
        self.states[self.c_state].enter()


class Individual(object):
    def __init__(self, name, food, sleep):
        self.name = name
        self.food = food
        self.sleep = sleep


class Wander():
    @staticmethod
    def enter():
        print('Entering Wander State')

    @staticmethod
    def execute(fsm):
        print('WANDERING')
        if fsm.individual.sleep <= 0:
            fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
        elif fsm.individual.food >= 25:
            fsm.changeState('WANDER')
            fsm.individual.sleep -= 5
            fsm.individual.food -= 5
        else:
            fsm.changeState('EAT')

    @staticmethod
    def exit():
        print('Leaving Wander State')


class Eat():
    @staticmethod
    def enter():
        print('Entering Eating State')

    @staticmethod
    def execute(fsm):
        print('EATING')
        if fsm.individual.sleep <= 0:
            fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
        elif fsm.individual.food < 25:
            fsm.changeState('EAT')
            fsm.individual.food += 5
            fsm.individual.sleep -= 5
        else:
            fsm.changeState('WANDER')

    @staticmethod
    def exit():
        print('Exiting Eating State')


class Sleep():
    @staticmethod
    def enter():
        print('Entering Sleeping State')

    @staticmethod
    def execute(fsm):
        print('SLEEPING')
        if fsm.individual.sleep < 50:
            fsm.changeState('SLEEP')
            fsm.individual.sleep += 5
        elif fsm.individual.food < 25:
            fsm.changeState('EAT')
        else:
            fsm.changeState('WANDER')

    @staticmethod
    def exit():
        print('Exiting Sleeping State')

aaron = Individual('aaron', 10, 30)

fsm = FSM(aaron)
fsm.addState('WANDER', Wander)
fsm.addState('EAT', Eat)
fsm.addState('SLEEP', Sleep)
fsm.startState('WANDER')
print(fsm.c_state)
fsm.update()
```